# Use Javascript .numeric function to allow only 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How do you use the `.numeric` function to only allow a specified number of decimal places? Below is the line of code I'm using:

```
 $('#Distance').numeric({ allow: "." });
```

Comment: You might be able to utilize the [`.toFixed()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)...

Comment: tried the following but did not work: `$('#Distance').numeric({ allow: "." }).toFixed(4)`

Comment: Well... I have zero knowledge about asp.net and I'm not familiar with that `numeric()` function you are using... The `toFixed()` function simply formats a number to a specified decimal point...

Comment: what is that element with ID Distance?

Comment: It's a single-line text-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear which plugin you're using, but I'm guessing it's one of these two:

texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/
auroratrading.co.th/js/

For both of them, they do not have a config option to restrict the number of numeric characters after the decimal place marker.

There's another jQuery plugin called meio mask that should let you accomplish what you want, see (decimal demo):
http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/#mm_demos

From a cursory glance at the page, you pick one of the 'masks' (in your case 'decimal-us') and assign it to the 'alt' attribute of an input element. After that you call the setMask method in your ready listener. Let me know if this works out for you!

Comment: Don't think I'm using this correctly. Does this look right:     `jQuery(function ($) {
        $('Distance[type="decimal-us"]').setMask()
    });`

Comment: Try: `$('#Distance').setMask()`  

Assuming that your input element has an id of 'Distance'.  

You'll need to add the alt="decimal-us" onto the actual input element in your html.

Answer (score 1):

if you have markup similar to

```
<input type="text" value="2.235323232"/>
```

try

```
$(":input").val(parseFloat($(":input").val()).toFixed(2));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WYyt3/